# Feathers client (@feathers/client) is unable to authenticate a username/password in an ReactJs app

Tags: reactjs, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

According to the [Featherjs Client Authentication docs](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/client.html#configuration), I have setup and initialised the module in my React App. After that on my `Login` button click, I call the recommended `app.authenticate(data)` method with the correct data format. This results in an error immediately `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined` in the `feathers.js` file from the client package.

It will be very helpful if you could point me to the right direction.

For this app:

1. I am currently working on development servers.
2. The ReactJs app is on localhost:3000
3. The FeathersJs app in on localhost:3030.
4. The React app is bootstrapped with CRA and the Feathers server is generated by the CLI.
5. In the React app I am using the `@feathersjs/client` package from npm.

I have already tried to request the server via `curl` in the terminal and that responds with the correct credentials. Following that, I made an AJAX request via the React app and that also worked. If I use AJAX request to do the authentication, I successfully get the `token` and the `id` of the user.

In reality I can further carry on. But the problem occurs to re-authenticate the user with the same token and to logout the user. I do understand that there are workarounds. But I would like to use the FeathersJs Client side as it provides ready to use `reAuthenticate` and `logout` methods.

**Initialising Feathers Client**

```js
import feathers from '@feathersjs/client';

const client = feathers();

client.configure(feathers.authentication({
  storage: window.localStorage
}));

export default client;
```

**`login` function in App.js called**

```js
login = () => {
      const self = this;
      client.authenticate({
        strategy: 'local',
        email: 'hello@robin.com',
        password: 'supersecret'
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        self.setState({
          isAuthenticated: true
        });
        return data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        self.setState({
          isAuthenticated: false
        });
      });
    };
```

When the function is called the following error is thrown:

In the dev console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
    at AuthenticationClient.authenticate (feathers.js:2838)
    at Object.App.login (App.js:50)
    at onClick (Login.js:8)
```

In the browser running the ReactJs application, the following error is shown:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined
AuthenticationClient.authenticate
node_modules/@feathersjs/client/dist/feathers.js:2838

> 2838 | var promise = this.service.create(authentication).then(function (authResult) {
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I make use of the FeathersJs client?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to initialize a [REST](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/rest.html#feathersjs-rest-client) or [Socket.io](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#feathersjs-socketio-client) client connection as also shown in the [React Native API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html#react-native). It should be

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
import feathers from '@feathersjs/feathers';
import socketio from '@feathersjs/socketio-client';

const socket = io('http://api.my-feathers-server.com', {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  forceNew: true
});
const client = feathers();

client.configure(socketio(socket));
client.configure(feathers.authentication({
  storage: window.localStorage
}));

export default client;
```